# How can I send a notification to Slack on publishing from Axure to AxShare?

Tags: notifications, slack

Like many web shops, we use Axure for wireframes and diagrams, Jira for Stories and Issues, and GitHub for code. We also use Slack for notifying developers of activity. Jira and GitHub both integrate beautifully with Slack. But Axure seems not to. This creates a bit of a problem in that developers are often not aware that a wireframe or a flow has changed.

How can I send a notification to Slack on publishing from Axure to AxShare?

Is it possible to configure Axure to send notifications to Slack?

If so, how?

If not natively supported, is there perhaps a hack that might allow something to monitor a website and alert Slack when something changes?

Answer (score 2):

MailClark is the integration you are looking for :) The bot allows you to send emails to & from Slack.
Just invite MailClark to a channel to receive Axure email alerts in Slack https://mailclark.ai/help/send-email-to-slack
Easy ;)

*Full disclosure: I work at MailClark*

Comment: If you are affiliated with the product, please disclose that in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

My gut instinct is to look for ways to run a remote "watch" against the published site.  If you were using axshare, this might require a 3rd-party service like the ones listed here:
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/detect-website-change-notification/

But if you were publishing locally, or on your own demo server then you might get some leverage out of automation tools like Grunt. http://gruntjs.com/ could help you automate the process of moving the files to the server as well as sending a note to Slack.

YMMV - I've never had to tackle this issue before, or have I used those services.